# Jquery find duplicate emails

Tags: jquery

I want to check for duplicate emails in the list, so I get a list of emails and then not sure how to loop it in order to compare each email in the list..

```
var emails = $('td.emails input');
emails.each(function(){

how to compare emails here

});
```

Comment: Do you want to just exclude duplicates?

Comment: Can you show some example HTML of your form? Is it one input with many emails or many input elements with one email each?

Comment: it's many input tags with one email each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hash to track uniqueness.  In Javascript, this means an object; try this:

```
var emails = $('td.emails input');
var found = {};

emails.each(function() {
    var email = $(this).val();

    if (email in found) {
        // duplicate!
    } else {
        found[email] = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

if you need to remove duplicates you can use [Jquery Unique](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/)

Comment: jQuery.unique() removes duplicates of DOM nodes. It won't work for different nodes which just happen to have the same values.

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrUnique(arr) {
    var o = {}, i, l = arr.length, r = [];
    for(i=0; i<l;i+=1) o[arr[i]] = arr[i];
    for(i in o) r.push(o[i]);
    return r;
};


var emails = $('td.emails input');
var emailArr = [];
emails.each(function(){
     emailArr.push($(this).val());
});

emailArr = arrUnique(emailArr);
```

Collects all input val that i suppose have the email text and remove duplicates. emailArr is an array with all the emails. You can them convert it back to an array, with emails separated by comma:

```
alert( emailArr.join(',') );
```

Unique array function taken from here: http://www.shamasis.net/2009/09/fast-algorithm-to-find-unique-items-in-javascript-array/

Comment: This won't work. See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kx7Ae/). $.unique() works with DOM nodes. See [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/). But you could use [_.uniq()](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#uniq) for that. See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FdaSA/).

Comment: I edited my answer to not use $.unique. My solution indeed works and according to some is the fastest way to do it.

Comment: @rsp I don't understand your $.unique demo. At least for me in chrome it's working. But yes, $.unique wasn't done for this, still, it seems to work in some cases.

Comment: @AlfaTeK — Mr. Bhattacharya is pointing out that using a hash is faster than a nested loop.  In this case, however, it's faster still to apply the hashing while looping over the elements (resulting in a single loop) rather than converting the element array into a value array, then a value hash, then back to a value array, which requires three loops.

Comment: @AlfaTeK: I tested my demo on Safari and it displayed: test1,test2,test1,test2. Now I see that on Firefox it displays test2,test1. The _.uniq() version seems to work consistently.